# Get 1-4 Items via Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to create awebapp where the user can choose between comparing 2,3 or 4 items of the database (Postgres).

i already could create a view function to query a fixed amount of items.

e.g query 3 Items

**View Function**

```
from myapp.models import Item

@api_view(['GET'])
def get_three_items(request, pk1, pk2, pk3):
    item1 = Item.objects.get(pk=pk1)
    item2 = Item.objects.get(pk=pk2)
    item3 = Item.objects.get(pk=pk3)
    data = [item1.serialize(), item2.serialize(), item3.serialize()]
    return Response(data)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import get_three_items

urlpatterns = [
    path('items/<int:pk1>/<int:pk2>/<int:pk3>/', get_three_items),
    # ...
]
```

But in my web app the user is able to choose between comparing 2,3 or 4 items.
Is there a way to write the View Function and URL in a way, that it is dynamic or do i have to create a view for each compare capacity. So a view to compare 2 items. A view to compare 3 items and a view to compare 4 items?

Comment: Create a url that accepts as parameters a list of ids, then in the view dynamically process these elements, do not put fixed 3 items in function params. Iterate through the list and dynamically create the data variable in your view. Also don't do 3 querys, just do somethin like: items = Item.objects.filter(pk__in=your_list_of_ids)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found the solution:

i adjusted PTomasz code a little. Try this version. It worked in my case.

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .models import Item


@api_view(['GET'])
def compare_items(request):
    items_ids = request.query_params.getlist('items_ids')
    items = Item.objects.filter(pk__in=items_ids)
    data = [serializer(item, many=False).data for item in items]
    return Response(data)
```

Comment: Worked also in my case. Thx @Russgo

Answer (score 1):

If passing ids in Query Params is an option, then you could do something like that:

views.py

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .models import Item


@api_view(['GET'])
def compare_items(request):
    items_ids = request.query_params.getlist('items_ids')
    items = Item.objects.filter(pk__in=items_ids)
    data = [item.serialize() for item in items]
    return Response(data)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import compare_items

urlpatterns = [
    path('items/', compare_items),
]
```

and then you can pass ids like that:

```
HOST/items/?items_ids=1&items_ids=3
```

Comment: I tried this. The Itmes_list gives me a QuerySet: <QuerySet [<Product: 8e03ac70>, <Product: ca57e9ae>]> but when i try to serialize each item i get the error: 'Item' object has no attribute 'serializer'

Comment: @Russgo Yes, that's because you have to create "serialize" method in your Model class and from what I can see in question user created it